# Photoshop CS6, Timeline reset

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

Is it possible to reset (means to remove all keyframes at once) timeline in Photoshop CS6? Thank you

I need this: to remove keyframes and timeline animation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the menu icon in the top right of the timeline:

[image]

You'll get this menu:

[image]

**Delete Animation** will delete every frame but the first one.

You can also click **Select All Frames** or select certain frames with Shift or Command and select **Delete Frames** to delete the selected frames. Again, the first frame remains as is.

Comment: thank you! But this is not exactly the same what I meant.

Comment: I added the extra info directly in the question, this way it's at the top of the page which is clearer for everyone and you have better chances of getting an answer. Does the document with the empty timeline have layers besides the background layer? As soon as you add a layer to the document it's added to the timeline, so that looks like an empty document to me; deleting a layer in the timeline also deletes it from the document. Otherwise you can click Select All Keyframes from the menu and press delete, which would delete all the keyframes but leave everything else intact.

Comment: thank you, Benoit.
It's more clear now. I have to add that before selecting All Keyframes it's necessary to select all layers which have Keyframes, otherwise, keyframes from unselected layers will remain. I didn't select all before and this was my fault.

Comment: Perfect! I'm glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

In case what you're actually wanting is to have a Frame Timeline vs a Video Timeline (or vice versa), there's a small icon in the bottom-left of the Timeline panel in CS6 that converts between the two Timeline types.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Note the menu items change based upon what *type* of animation is present.</sub>

- For a **Frame Animation**, use the pop up menu on the Timeline Panel and choose `Delete Animation`. This will remove all animation frames.

  [image]
- For a **Timeline Animation**, use the pop up menu on the Timeline Panel and choose `Delete Timeline`. This will remove all timeline layers and keyframes, reverting back to your screenshot, having no timeline present.
  [image]

Comment: thank you, Scott, but I'm afraid your screenshots not of Adobe Photoshop SC6, but Adobe Photoshop CC. I don't have "Delete Timeline" option in CS6.
http://i1382.photobucket.com/albums/ah271/fozz95/Untitle3d-1_zpsqbp7hzth.jpg

Comment: @VictorChernobay I launched CS6 It does appear to be a feature Adobe added to CC. In CS6, you'll merely have to shift-click the timeline tracks and hit the delete key until they are all gone.